# How to open winmail.dat file email attachment?

Tags: applications, email

My boss can't open attachments in his Lenovo K3 NOTE and all he got was a `winmail.dat` file. What settings should I use to get rid of `winmail.dat` file and open the attachments?

Answer (score 2):

Microsofts Outlook e-mail program sometimes sends e-mail attachments as "Transport Neutral Encapsulation Format" (TNEF). This attachment is usually named "WINMAIL.DAT".

You should install the [Winmail.dat Opener](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.treinhardt.android.winmaildat&hl=en)(1.7mb) or [Free Winmail Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=icab.winmail&hl=en)(6.9mb) app from the play-store. Opening the file will reveal you multiple files packed into it just like a zip file.

> ## How to open a winmail.dat file?
>
> 1. Select `Winmail.dat Opener` from the context menu of the `winmail.dat` attachment.
> 2. Start `Winmail.dat Opener` and use the built-in file dialog to select a previously saved winmail.dat file. Once you are at the
>      contained files list, you can long click a file to open it or select
>      files and click the "save" icon from the action bar to save all
>      selected files to the sdcard. All files will be saved to a directory
>      called "winmaildatopener".
> 3. After successful export of a file to this
>      directoy an open file dialog will enable you to start further actions,
>      like open, share on the exported files.